# Is there any purpose to Barren planets?

Tags: starbound

Some planets are 100% barren. It appears that they have no caves or resources of any kind. Is there some secret point to them, or are they literally just... barren?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from http://starbounder.org/Barren:

"Barren worlds are well suited to building because of their safe environment and relatively flat topography."
Barren worlds have no spawns, so you can bring in farming supplies to create a farm that doesn't have to worry about mob spawns.

Comment: What a lonely place to live though...

Comment: @Aventinus Actually, they're wonderful places to build. Thanks to the colony system, you can get a really populated outpost going, plus you are also able to grow trees and plants for a wide variety of plantlife. Add some captured creatures and you've got a very nice planet, without the dangers of a regular planet.

Comment: @MageXy I build on asteroid fields, that's wonderful :) Not sure if they allow colonies though.